# Como consigo la palabra mas repetida de un diccionario?

Tags: python-3.x, diccionarios, random

Si tengo el diccionario `h={'arbol':3, 'casa':10, 'perro':2, 'gato':5}` donde las llaves son palabras que aparecen en un texto y los valores son las veces que se repite cada palabra, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que se escoja aleatoriamente una de las palabras teniendo en cuenta su probabilidad?
Me han dicho que con `random.choice` se puede hacer, pero no lo consigo.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? No has conseguido hacerlo, pero si muestras lo que has intentado se te puede orientar y corregir para que aprendas mejor qué estabas haciendo mal y por qué no funcionaba :)

Comment: Hola OierL, aparte de lo comentado por Rabegi, **planteas una cosa en el título (obtener clave de un diccionario con valor mayor) y otra en el cuerpo de la pregunta (escoger aleatoriamente)**. En cuanto a escoger aleatoriamente, ¿te refieres a tener en cuenta las veces que se repite? Es decir, para `h={'arbol':20, 'casa':5}` la probabilidad de que se seleccione "árbol" es del 20/25 (80%) y la de "casa" 5/25 (20%).

Comment: Supongo que la función que quieres usar es [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), en plural. Pero como dice @FJSevilla, la redacción de la pregunta es contradictoria. Corrígela para que podamos concretar la respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a algo así:

```
import random

h={'arbol':3, 'casa':10, 'perro':2, 'gato':5}

d=[]
for i in h:
    for j in range(int(h[i])):
        d.append(i)
```

Donde podremos comprobar el resultado de esta forma:

```
r={}
for i in h:
    r[i]=0
for i in range(int(2e3)):
    r[random.choice(d)]+=1
print(r)
```

Obteniendo un resultado `r` similar a éste:

```
{'arbol': 287, 'casa': 991, 'perro': 193, 'gato': 529}
```

Espero que te resulte últil. Cualquier duda, déjamela en los comentarios para documentar mejor la respuesta.